# Using pointers in C? Confused

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, exec, fork

Here is a piece of code I'm trying to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
/* Spawn a child process running a new program. PROGRAM is the name
 of the program to run; the path will be searched for this program.
 ARG_LIST is a NULL-terminated list of character strings to be
 passed as the program’s argument list. Returns the process ID of
 the spawned process. */

int spawn (char* program, char** arg_list)
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    /* Duplicate this process. */
    child_pid = fork ();
    if (child_pid != 0)
    /* This is the parent process. */
        return child_pid;
    else {
        /* Now execute PROGRAM, searching for it in the path. */
        execvp (program, arg_list);
        /* The execvp function returns only if an error occurs. */
        fprintf (stderr, “an error occurred in execvp\n”);
        abort ();
    }
}

int main ()
{
    /* The argument list to pass to the “ls” command. */
    char* arg_list[] = {
        “ls”, /* argv[0], the name of the program. */
        “-l”,
        “/”,
        NULL /* The argument list must end with a NULL. */
    };
    /* Spawn a child process running the “ls” command. Ignore the
     returned child process ID. */
    spawn (“ls”, arg_list);
    printf (“done with main program\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding how the pointers for the spawn function work. The parameters it asks for are `char* program`, and `char** arglist`. In the main method, we are calling the method and passing in `"ls"` and `char* arglist[]`, which I understand is an array of pointers. How does `char* program` correspond to `"ls"`, since `"ls"` is not a pointer to a `char`. And how does `char** arglist`, which is a pointer to a pointer to a char correspond to `char* arglist[]`, which is an array of pointers?
I'm just having trouble understanding how the pointers work in this code example.

Also, in `main`, for `char* arg_list[]`, are we basically storing pointers to each character? Like for example, `arg_list[0]` will hold the address of `"l"`, `arg_list[1]` will hold address of `"s"`, `arg_list[2]` will hold address of `"-"`

Comment: C strings are a sequence of chars terminated by a 0, so you'd reference them by a pointer to the first char in the string. Ditto an array is a sequence of values in consecutive memory locations, so `char[]` is (more or less) equivalent to `char*`.

Comment: FYI, `arg_list[0]` is a pointer to `"ls"`, `arg_list[1]` is a pointer to `"-l"`, `arg_list[2]` is a pointer to `"/"`, and `arg_list[4]` is a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @Rup: More less than more. And knowing the exact differences matters.

Comment: BTW: Beware of the not-so-smart smart-quotes you have used. They are wrong.

Comment: BTW: `“an error occurred in execvp\n”` You have strange quotation marks.

Comment: @wildplasser that's smart quotes but will be thought as "stupid" by the compiler

Answer (score 1):

You are using smart-quotes in your code. Correct that, and find out why you got them. They are simply wrong and your program won't compile with them.

An array of `char*` of length deduced from the initializer:

```
char* arg_list[] = {
```

The elements are initialized from a string-literal, which is a 0-terminated array of non-modifiable `char`-elements. Those arrays decay to pointers to their first elements on use:

```
   "ls", "-l", "/", NULL };
```

BTW: `NULL` in a pointer-context is a null-pointer-constant. Never forget to cast it in an ambiguous context (ellipsis, no-prototype-function).

Both arrays below decay on call to pointers to their first elements:

```
spawn ("ls", arg_list);
```

BTW: Constant compound literals (C99) and string-literals (since forever) can be merged to save space.

There's not much to be said about your `spawn()`-function...